How to fix a dependency missing when posting a notification in a java plugin associated to a Unity project?
I am writing a plugin for my Unity-made android app, using Android Studio.
It's main goal is to contact a server regularly to check for other users activity and post a notification if so.
I'm doing this because it can run as a background service and thus start when the phone boots without having the main app running.
Although all the networking stuff is working flawlessly, I'm having issues with NotificationCompat.Builder.
Here is the code I'm using.
In my java plugin:
createNotificationChannel();
     
// Notification creation
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(serviceContext, "opu_intranet_notification_channel")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.main_icon)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
        .setContentText(notificationText)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT) // Used in Android < 8.0*/
        .build(); // <------- THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS
 
// Notification post
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)serviceContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(activityId), notification);

I added this to my AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

And finally the error I get in logcat when the app crashes:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Landroidx/core/app/NotificationCompat$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Builder' appears in /data/app/~~rj5V5KmB6jWWSJyloD1swg==/com.opu.securityconcilapp-Tqvpkq0MSxWr6uPzxG6T8Q==/base.apk)

What I tried.
Throughout my searches, I found this post that describes the exact same problem, but it is almost 10 years old and the solution doesn't work (I tried adding the most recent equivalent *.aar library to my Plugin/Android folder in Unity, but the build then fails, and I couldn't find the appropriate androidx.core library).
I also tried to add this to proguard-user.txt:

-keep class androidx.core.app.** { *; }

Finally, in a "stand-alone" app made with Android Studio, it works perfectly, that I'm 99% sure it's a problem with Unity dependencies.
Using unity-jar-resolver fails to suggest any missing dependency in Unity Editor.
Software details
OS: Xubuntu 22.04
Android Studio: Jellyfish 2023.3.1
Unity: 2022.3.20f1
Phone: Samsung Galaxy A52s - Android 14 (API 34)
Thanks in advance for your time! :)
